# The way to save streaming file (video or audio or both) through database and its effective

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hadoop, streaming

I plan to make rtsp server that provides video or audio, saved live, such as camera video data.

So I'm searching how to save these data.

It will be quite a lot of files, about 10 ~ 10000. Each of that file size will be around 4GB.

First time, I think each of files made just files and write index data to DB.
It is the best simple and easy work i think.

But how about save data directly to DB??? such as using blob.
I seemed it looks much more easier than first thing if i deal DB well.

Of course I searched in case of MySQL, MSSQL.

Most of them are negative. then **how about big database? such as hadoop or NoSQL?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i decided only index in db!
there is so much disadvantages insert video data in db.

Comment: That is fine. How & where are you storing videos now? Indexing in DB si fine.

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution.

1) You will store videos in **content delivery network (CDN)**. Have a location of video.

2) In your NoSQL database like **HBase**, store **ImageId** (or Image Name) and **Location** of Image.

3) Other solution : Use **Solr** Indexing coupled with **Cassandra**. Images are stored in Cassandra & Index is stored in Solr. You will get images from Cassandra using Solr index.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your reply.
i just save in directory. and write index to db sametime.

I really think about NoSQL's ImageId (it seemed like blob data)
but, i'm not sure, if this is right way or not.

Comment: plus, i will not use cdn. it only uses in closed network.